# Unexpected error when using a typedef for an integral type

Tags: c++, g++, typedef

I've googled around and can't find anyone else with a similar problem, which is weird since it seems like people would run into this fairly regularly.  Can someone explain why this snippet produces an error:

```
typedef long mytype_t;
void function(unsigned mytype_t foo) {}
```

But this second, nearly identical snippet does not?

```
typedef long mytype_t;
void function(mytype_t unsigned foo) {}
```

I'm using g++ 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `typedef mytype_t long;` is incorrect. anyways .. typedef is not equivalent to string substitution. so if you want `mytype_t == unsigned long` u have to specify so.. because `unsigned long` does not mean `signed long` which is often simplified to `long`

Answer (score 2):

The order of the typedef "parameters" is backwards--it should be `typedef long mytype_t`. I'm actually surprised either one compiled (VC++ rejects both).

But even after switching them, it still isn't going to let you prefix a typedef type with `unsigned`.

Comment: I think I mistranscribed the typedef line.  Nonetheless, this doesn't answer the question, which is "why can't I use `unsigned [typedef type]`?".

Comment: You can't add 'unsigned' to a `typedef`'d type because the standard says you can't.  It isn't allowed.